# Redux Form props not displaying in event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am building a very simple front end app to connect a few API's. I have a redux form that should trigger an event handler which then triggers an action creator. The event handler is not receiving any props at present (just getting an empty object). This is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import fetchConcerts from '../actions/fetchConcerts.js'

class ListContainer extends Component {

  handleFormSubmit(formProps){
    event.preventDefault()
    debugger
    this.props.fetchConcerts(formProps)

  }


  render(){
    const { fields: { userCity, userDate }, handleSubmit } = this.props;


        return (
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))} >
                <label>City</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-input" {...userCity} />
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-input" {...userDate} />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }


export default reduxForm({
      form: 'search',
      fields: ['userCity', 'userDate']
    }, null, { fetchConcerts })(ListContainer);
```

App.js (the parent component) is as follow-->

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListContainer from './containers/ListContainer.js'
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ListContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Upon submit, the handleFormSubmit is kicked off and I hit my debugger but formProps is Object = {}

Any ideas? I have run into this problem quite a bit with redux forms but I can never really figure out where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: what version of redux-form are you using?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a valid version: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/tags?after=v4.0.4. if indeed you are using that old version, you might want to try using the latest (6.x) since the creator has fixed a ton of bugs

Comment: Hmmm when I try to update any packages npm is throwing me a huge laundry list of errors. Here is one of the issues it seems:                             npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-redux@^4.3.0, required by redux-form@6.0.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: redux@^3.0.0, required by redux-form@6.0.5

Comment: so i resolved dependencies and updated everything--no errors and using redux-form 6.0.5 and still having same issue

Comment: What happens if you move your `handleFormSubmit` method into `App`, then add `<ListContainer onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />`

Comment: so that works but I still am getting `props = Object {}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the values entered in the input fields? If yes, this may be helpful:

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Access value and attributes of the City input
  console.log(event.target.elements[0].value);
  console.log(event.target.elements[0].attributes);

  // Access value and attributes of the Date input
  console.log(event.target.elements[1].value);
  console.log(event.target.elements[1].attributes);    
}
```

A working demo here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/vXXXaJ

Comment: redux forms should wrap the component so you don't need to do that--it should, when working, automatically pass the input values to the props. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Although i haven't used `redux-form`, I think the issue is with your code, You can change your `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))} >` to

```
<form
    onSubmit={ (event) => {
            handleSubmit( this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this, event, formProps) );
        }
    }
>
```

And your **handleFormSubmit** function to

```
handleFormSubmit(event, formProps){
    event.preventDefault()
    debugger
    this.props.fetchConcerts(formProps)
}
```

**EDIT #1**

After going through `redux-form` documentation, you could change the form to

```
<form
    onSubmit={ (event) => {
            handleSubmit( data => { this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this, event, data) } );
        }
    }
>
```

And it should work.

---

And to simplify things even further

You can change your `form component` code to

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit( data => { this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this, data) } ) } >
```

And `handleFormSubmit` function to

```
handleFormSubmit(data){
    console.log('form data', data);
    this.props.fetchConcerts(data)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I'm still getting the same issue and now it wants me to declare formProps somewhere.. the documentation for redux-forms is pretty bad :-/ playing around with everything now

Comment: @tqr_aupa_atleti updated the answer, Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: thanks! yeah it's bypassing my event handler entirely with the above code. This is very odd, I feel like I had the exact same code as in a previous project.